# Do the pilots shown match the ships flown?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

[image]

In this screen capture from Star Wars, A New Hope, I counted 28 orange flight suits. I assume Luke Skywalker is in the lower right corner, so lets call it 29 pilots give or take. Now my question is this, do we ever see on screen a matching count of X-Wings and Y-Wings attacking the Death Star?

Comment: You missed at least one ... the dude to 27's left ... he's holding a helmet in front of him.

Comment: @Paulster2, I agree, there a few in there that were very hard to see. I only marked the ones I knew for sure were wearing a flight suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**. There are approx 30 pilots in your pic and approx 30 ships seen in the space-scene that immediately follows.

[image]

As an aside, it's worth noting that the events of the (Disney-canon) comic series [Princess Leia](http://marvel.com/comics/series/19631/princess_leia_2015_-_present) indicate that there was at least one Alderaanian [x-wing pilot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Evaan_Verlaine) who's not featured in your picture.

[image]

Comment: I notice that the example photo is actually from a later release of Star Wars, do you believe that Lucas came back and specifically addressed this issue of a low number of fighters compared to a high number of pilots shown?

Comment: @chris - Short answer, yes.

Comment: @Chris - Lucas would **never** do that!

Comment: Lucas specifically said that he was disappointed with not being able to show more X-Wings at the time of production. At the time, budget/time constraints only allowed the brief shot of 5-ish fighters approaching the Death Star.